# Sanitize ASP.NET Core's automatic 400 responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

When an action receives bad inputs, the runtime's [automatic 400 response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#automatic-http-400-responses) feature generates a `ProblemDetails` which contains an error message (`errors.$[0]`) like this:

```
"The JSON value could not be converted to CompanyName.Foo.Bar. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 3."
```

I don't want to leak implementation details.

How can I exclude `CompanyName.Foo.Bar`?

(I'm using ASP.NET Core 5, with API controllers, not MVC.)

Comment: Use a `ViewModel` and internally map that to domain objects, so that your only "leaking" your viewmodel, i.e what a consumer of your app/ API already knows they need to provide

Comment: I wouldn't really consider that "leaking implementation details". Your API accepts some JSON, and if the JSON doesn't match the expected format, then what harm is them in telling them what the proper format is? This isn't the same as leaking exception messages or configuration settings or any of the detail about how the server side code is actually implemented.

Comment: Exposing `CompanyName.Foo.Bar.CustomerType` is definitely leaking implementation details.

Comment: @MindSwipe That's a decent idea, but sometimes you want to bind to some simple type directly without the ceremony of a viewmodel / inputmodel, in which case you get this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me share with you our implementation of a custom response in case of Model Binding error.

First, let's define an interface which contains a method that can be passed to the `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`:

```
public interface IModelBindingErrorHandler
{
    IActionResult HandleInvalidModelState(ActionContext context);
}
```

Let's continue by defining two models. One for logging and another for response:

```
public class InvalidInputModel
{
    public string FieldName { get; init; }
    public string[] Errors { get; init; }

    public override string ToString() => $"{FieldName}: {string.Join("; ", Errors)}";
}

public class GlobalErrorModel
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; init; }
    public string ErrorTracingId { get; init; }
}
```

As you can see, both of them are generic enough to be used in other error handlers as well.

Now let's implement the `IModelBindingErrorHandler` interface:

```
public class ModelBindingErrorHandler : IModelBindingErrorHandler
{
    private ILogger<ModelBindingErrorHandler> logger;

    public ModelBindingErrorHandler(ILogger<ModelBindingErrorHandler> logger)
        => this.logger = logger;
    
    public IActionResult HandleInvalidModelState(ActionContext context)
    {
        var modelErrors = context.ModelState
            .Where(stateEntry => stateEntry.Value.Errors.Any())
            .Select(stateEntry => new InvalidInputModel
            {
                FieldName = stateEntry.Key,
                Errors = stateEntry.Value.Errors.Select(error => error.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
            });

        var traceId = Guid.NewGuid();
        logger.LogError("Invalid input model has been captured. ModelState: {modelErrors}, TraceId: {traceId}", modelErrors, traceId);

        return new BadRequestObjectResult(new GlobalErrorModel
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Sorry, the request contains invalid data. Please revise.",
            ErrorTracingId = traceId.ToString()
        });
    }
}
```

- So, here we basically collect all valuable information (`Errors`) and we are logging them
- We connect the log entry with the response by using a `traceId`

  - I've used here a `Guid.NewGuid()` instead of a correlationId for the sake of simplicity

In order to make the usage of this implementation easy here are two extension methods for self-registration:

```
public static class ModelBindingErrorHandlerRegister
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddModelBinderErrorHandler(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return AddModelBinderErrorHandler<ModelBindingErrorHandler>(services);
    }

    public static IServiceCollection AddModelBinderErrorHandler<TImpl>(this IServiceCollection services)
        where TImpl : class, IModelBindingErrorHandler
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IModelBindingErrorHandler, TImpl>();

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var handler = serviceProvider.GetService<IModelBindingErrorHandler>();
        services.Configure((ApiBehaviorOptions options) =>
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = handler.HandleInvalidModelState);

        return services;
    }
}
```

- The first method registers the above implementation
- The second method allows to register a custom one if needed
- The `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` assignment can be done inside the `PostConfigure` as well

---

With these in our hand we can register a custom model binder handler with a single line:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddModelBinderErrorHandler();
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. My solution "fixes" the problem, whereas your solution avoids the problem. However, your solution doesn't respond with a standardized `ProblemDetails` but that is very easy to do. I think this is the better approach. Thanks!

Comment: @Ionix Whenever we have used `ProblemDetails` for user facing APIs we had received some feedback that the error is not really intuitive. That's why we come up with a simple model. We have used the `ProblemDetails` for service to service communication.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution. There could be a better / easier / perfer way.

In `Startup.ConfigureServices()`:

```cs
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(o => {
  o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext => {

    var problemsDetailsFactory = actionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ProblemDetailsFactory>();

    var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
    foreach (var key in actionContext.ModelState.Keys) {
      var value = actionContext.ModelState[key];
      foreach (var error in value.Errors) {
        var errorMessage = Regex.Replace(error.ErrorMessage, @"^(The JSON value could not be converted)( to .*)(\. Path:.*)$", "$1$3");
        modelState.AddModelError(key, errorMessage);
      }
    }

    var problemDetails = problemsDetailsFactory.CreateValidationProblemDetails(actionContext.HttpContext, modelState, StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);
    return new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails);
  };
});
```

That sanitises:

```
"The JSON value could not be converted to CompanyName.Foo.Bar. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 3."
```

To:

```
"The JSON value could not be converted. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 3."
```

Comment: Are these information (`Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 3`) useful for the your clients?

Comment: @PeterCsala Nope, in my code I've removed those too.